# How to close cmd window when using a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

New to batch files, first try actually. Trying to make a simple batch file that will open a new instance of notpad++.  The batch file works and a new notpad++ window is opened, but the cmd window also stays open as well.  How do I close the cmd window within the batch file after the new instance of notepad has been lauched?

```
@ECHO OFF

CALL cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\

CALL notepad++.exe -multiInst
```

Comment: You can't since the batch file called notepad++.  Why are you calling it from a batch file instead of making a shortcut?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `start`:

```
start notepad++
```

And there should be no need to use an explicit `exit` from the batch (which is done either via `goto :eof` or `exit /b`) as the `start` call returns immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You can exit from command line only after quiting from notepad++.
1. If you wanna exit from cmd after quiting from notepad++, add EXIT to the end of your batch file.
2. Why don't you use shortcut instead of batch file to start notepad++?

Comment: The usual reason is lack of support for relative paths in shortcuts