# Launch an Application from a Browser

Tags: java, javascript, html, vim

I would like to have a link or button on my web site that launches
vim (an editor) on a specific file (e.g., myfile.txt) on my local machine.
I want to launch C:\Vim\Vim74\gvim.exe on C:\Users\paulco\myfile.txt form any browser.

I want this to work on all (realistically most) browsers.
I actively use Chrome, Opera, FireFox and IE (in that order of preference).
In order for it to work across all of these browsers,
I think the script has to Java-based.

Does anyone know how to do this?
Does anyone have a Java-based script that does this?

Here are some resources I found on the topic.
But either they are IE specific or don't work.
[Launch application from a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057576/launch-application-from-a-browser)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: so what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the following on Internet Explorer, Chrome, Opera and Firefox.

The browser has to run on a Windows operating system, Linux and Mac require different aproaches.

Solution is to define a [protocol handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28VS.85%29.aspx) for a custom protocol.

1) Take this HTML example, it should open the specified text file using notepad.exe:

```
<a href="test:c:\temp\file.txt">Open Textfile</a>
```

2) You need to define the protocol handler in the windows registry, save the following to a file named testing.reg and execute it (double click on it), or enter the values manually using regedit:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\test]
@="URL:Editor test"
"URL Protocol"=hex(2):00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\test\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\test\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\test\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\test\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\temp\\editor.bat\" %1"
```

3) As you can see, I am not calling notepad.exe directly, but a `c:\temp\editor.bat` batch file. This is because the file-parameter has to be modified. using the `%1` as a parameter will pass the complete URL including the `test:` custom protocol name to the shell. In the script, I use a simple substring pattern to extract the specified file name and call the editor:

```
REM editor.bat
set param=%1
notepad %param:~5%
```

That's all!

Comment: I tried your solution, and it almost works!
When I try it out from Chrome, Opera, FireFox and IE, I get the same results:
notepad opens but to the wrong file.
For example, here's what happens when I use Opera (on Windows 7), which is installed in C:\Opera\
When I hover over the link, it shows: "test:c:\temp\file.txt"
But when I click the link, notepad shows the path to the file as being: "C:\Opera\test:c:\temp\file.txt"
Not sure why it is including the path to Opera's executable. I tried modifying the bat script to include the full path to notepad.exe but that didn't work.

Comment: Interesting, what version of Windows you are using? If I find some time, I will have a deeper look at it. But in any case, you are able to call a batch script from a browser's link - I expected a little more enthusiasm! ;-)

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 Professional. And yes, I'm very excited that it almost works. You're so close I can taste it! WOOOO HOOOO! Is that enough enthusiasm! :-)

Comment: Udo Klimaschewski, You stated: "If I find some time, I will have a deeper look at it."

Do you have some extra time to look at it. You're almost there, all we need to figure out is why does the %1 contain the path of the browser when it executes.

Comment: I have checked it with Windows-7 and IE,FF and Opera. It works without a problem. Maybe you have some special modified system, or you have not copied exactly the right data. E.g. a mistake in the registry settings or the batch scipt. Better check it on another system, I have now tried 3 different PCs, works fine on all of them (Win-7, 8.0 and 8.1)

Comment: I finally got it to work by implementing your exact code (which works). What I did in the begining is I changed the URL Protocol from @="URL:Editor test" to @="URL:Editor openvim" it didn't like that. The name of the bat file also had to be editor.bat. Without making those changes, the editor (gvim) would open a file but with the wrong file path (the  path included the path to the browser). So my suggestion to everyone is to copy the code verbatim and don't make any changes (other than the program you want executed, I changed that to gvim instead of notepad).

Comment: Fine! Of course, you can change the protocol name, but then you have to change also the other references. Please don't forget to accept the answer, thanks.

Comment: When the editor opens the file a cmd window stays open until you close the opened file. Is there a way to open the file without leaving an open cmd window. In other words, is there a way to call the edit command "notpad file.txt" with an ampersand "notepad file.txt &"

Comment: @user3145909 Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895287/how-to-close-cmd-window-when-using-a-batch-file